# Hide a cell from gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable

I have a winform c# SQL app in which i retrieve some values to a datagrid view and from there on wards i will display them to a user.

however there are certain gridcells which have values that i don't want to show to the user, and i want to hide them,

here is my code to hide cell values.

```
CurrencyManager cm =   (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource=dmz.Tables[0]];
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {

            if (dgvr.Cells[51].Value.ToString() == "N/A") //object reference not  set to an instance of the object  exception is thrown
                {

                    cm.SuspendBinding();
                    dgvr.Visible = false;
                }
```

there is an *object reference not  set to an instance of the object  exception* thrown...
what is triggering the error?
Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Change

`if (dgvr.Cells[51].Value.ToString() == "N/A")`
to

`if (dgvr.Cells[51].Value??"").ToString() == "N/A")`

or

`if (dgvr.Cells[51].Value!=null && dgvr.Cells[51].Value.ToString() == "N/A")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DataGridView_CellFormatting event method .

Like this:

```
private void dgvr_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
 if(dgvr.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["51"].Value!=null && dgvr[51].Value.ToString()=="N/A")
  {
    dgvr.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["51"].Value="";
  }
}
```